# Building a Qt executable in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, qt

I made a Qt Application in Visual Studio and it works when I run it in the program. However then I build the solution and try to run the executable errors pop up that certain .dll files are not found(QtWidgets.dll, QtCore.dll,QtCored.dll etc.). How can I fix this?

Comment: Install the required DLLs along with your program. You'll need both some Qt libraries as well as the Visual Studio runtime libraries.

Comment: You can also add entries to the the windows `PATH` environment variable in your project settings `Debugging -> Environment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your application ready for deployment, you can use **`windeployqt`**.
It is a commandline program that comes with Qt and collects all the required dependencies of your executable. Go to your `QTDIR/bin/` folder and run this command

```
windeployqt <path-to-app-binary.exe>
```

It will scan your binary and copy everything that is needed next to it. For further details, have a look at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two options:

1. If you want to distribute your application, you have to copy the required DLLs to the folder where your executable is. You can do this either by copying them manually or you write a script for this. The DLLs are in the binary folder of your Qt installation, e.g.

> Qt\5.12.2\mingw73_64\bin

2. Add the above mentioned folder to your system PATH variable, then the DLLs should be found by your application.

Comment: No need to do this manually or writing your own scrip. Qt comes with a tool named `windeployqt` that does exactly this.